# Get XML sub-elements and contents as text

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have a full XML document that I am successfully navigating with LINQ to XML. I have a sub-node that contains HTML and I want to get the full text of the sub-node as a string.

```
...
<p>
  this is sample text in <italic>italic</italic> and in <bold>bold</bold>.
</p>
...
```

`var text = node.Element("p").Value` returns `this is sample text in italic and in bold.`

`var text = node.Element("p").ToString()` returns `<p>this is sample text in <italic>italic</italic> and in <bold>bold</bold>.</p>`

What I really want is `this is sample text in <italic>italic</italic> and in <bold>bold</bold>.`

What method will return the inner text along with the inner tags as a string? I don't want the outer `<p>` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var reader = node.Element("p").CreateReader();
reader.MoveToContent();
var inerXml = reader.ReadInnerXml();
```

OR

```
var inerXml = string.Concat(node.Element("p").Nodes().Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray());
```

Comment: I went looking for that but don't see it as a property on the Element() result.

Comment: Thanks. Just came up with that myself after a bit more searching. Should make for a nice extension method!

Answer (score 1):

## Try this out:-

You can directly use `innerXml` property to get the inner content of `p` tag as xml.

```
namespace XML_Reader
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
            xdoc.Load("test.xml");
            XmlNode elem = xdoc.DocumentElement.FirstChild;

            Console.WriteLine(elem.InnerXml);       
        }
    }
}
```

**XML:-**

```
<element>
  <p>
    this is sample text in <italic>italic</italic> and in <bold>bold</bold>.
  </p>
</element>
```

**Output:-**

```
  this is sample text in <italic>italic</italic> and in <bold>bold</bold>.
```

Comment: Interesting approach but I am not working with xdocs but rather Linq to XML.